# Coideal Definition

Tags: category-theory, coalgebras

In a coalgebra $A$ with comultiplication $\Delta$ and counit $\epsilon$, a two-sided coideal is defined to be a linear subspace satisfying $\Delta (I) \subseteq A\otimes I + I \otimes A$ and $I \subseteq \operatorname{ker} (\epsilon)$.

How do I understand this as the categorical dual notion of an ideal of an algebra (or ring), which is defined by $rI \subseteq I$ and $Ir \subseteq I$ for $r \in A$? I am particularly confused why there is an "additional" kernel condition for a coideal, which does not seem present in the definition of an ideal.

Comment: In the dual picture for Hopf algebras coideals are like indicator functions on (set) complements of subgroups. The first condition saying that something in this set is not a product of elements in the subgroup, and the second saying the identity is not in this set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\Delta(I) \subseteq A\otimes I + I\otimes A$ part is easier, so let's begin with that! If we have a ring $R$ and we denote its multiplication by $m\colon R\otimes R\to R$, then any two-sided ideal $I$ of $R$ satisfies both $m(R\otimes I)\subseteq I$ and $m(I\otimes R)\subseteq I$. It then follows that $m(R\otimes I + I\otimes R)\subseteq I$. The "reverse all arrows in the diagrams" logic then also flips the subset sign, and this provides the first condition.

The second condition boils down to the idea that we want (co)ideals to be such that the corresponding quotients are (co)algebras. Furthermore, we want the projection $p\colon C\to C/I$ to be a natural morphism of (co)algebras. For this to be true, we need $\varepsilon_C = \varepsilon_{C/I}\circ p$. For the sake of argument, let's suppose that there is an element $c\in I$ but $c\not\in\ker(\varepsilon_C)$. Then, by definition, $\varepsilon_C(c)\neq0$ but $(\varepsilon_{C/I}\circ p)(c) = \varepsilon_{C/I}(0) = 0$, causing a problem!

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! For the second condition, is the dual statement for an ideal? Is it that the image of $\eta$ does not include $I$? Also, is there an easy diagrammatic definition of an ideal/coideal such that you can really see that such things are "arrow-reversed" partners?

Comment: You're welcome! I can't remember how to do diagrams here now, so I'll show them to you later (if needed). If we are dealing with unital algebras, then we have to either exclude the one-element ring or use the convention that in its case 0=1. In the latter case, we may without hesitation take the projection $p\colon A\to A/A = 0$, for which the condition "$\text{im}(\eta_A)\not\subseteq I$" does not hold. If we do require $0\neq1$, then we need $I\subsetneq A$, and then $\text{im}(\eta_A)\not\subseteq I$, or your proposition but with the inclusion reversed!

Comment: For the diagram, you should write $m\colon A\otimes_RA\to A$ for the multiplication. Then let $m_|$ be its restriction to $A\otimes_RI + I\otimes_RA\to I$ (if in doubt, check this!) and then connect these with the inclusions $A\otimes_RI+I\otimes_RA\to A\otimes_RA$ and $I\to A$ to get a square. To dualise the operations (not the inclusions as coideals are sub and not quotient objects!), we flip $m, m_|$ around to get $\Delta\colon C\to C\otimes_RC$ and its restriction $\Delta_|\colon I\to C\otimes_RI+I\otimes_RC$.